# ERROR in ../node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts:3:68 - error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am getting this error when trying run the angular application using `ng serve`.
Here are the details of the project

```
Angular CLI: 8.2.0
Node: 14.19.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.0
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.802.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.802.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.802.0
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.802.0
@angular-devkit/core              8.2.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.2.0
@angular/cdk                      8.1.2
@angular/flex-layout              8.0.0-beta.26
@angular/http                     7.2.15
@angular/material                 8.1.2
@ngtools/webpack                  8.2.0
@schematics/angular               8.2.0
@schematics/update                0.802.0
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack                           4.38.0
```

I have node version `v14.19.1` and `"@types/node": "^14.14.31",`.

Comment: It would be useful to know what command/code you are running that is resulting in the error in the question title. Also, deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling all deps is always a good first debugging step.

Comment: I am running `ng serve` command. I have already tried to deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` completely and then `npm install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by modifying the version of `@types/node` and `typescript` in `package.json`. So there is version incompatibility between `typescript` and `@types/node`. Below is what I am using now in the `package.json`.

```
"@types/node": "15.6.1",
"typescript": "3.5.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get tsc compile errors similar to this, and verify that you have the correct latest versions of @types/node and typescript in your package.json file, then try upgrading your globally installed version of typescript.

```
npm -g upgrade typescript
```